# How to put ThemeDictionaries into the App.xaml?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have an UWP app that have to be multi-theme (with dark and light themes).

How I sholud create ThemeDictionary and how I should put it into the App.xaml (I want it to be like "global" in my app, not as PageResources)?

Now it looks like this:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="White" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="Black" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="Black" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="White" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

... and now (regardless of where ThemeDictionary is placed), XAML throws the following error:
`XDG0046    Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.`

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `<ResourceDictionary>` element inside **`<Application.Resources>`** element, following is the code sample.

```
<Application
    x:Class="yourAppName.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:yourAppName">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="Red" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="Green" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="Blue" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="Yellow" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

---

```
 <Button Content="Button" Background="{ThemeResource BackgroundBrush}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
```